# FD_ACCEPT detected, but then call 'accept' fails with 10038 - WSAENOTSOCK

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

Well basically, that is it. Meanwhile, the client's call to connect is a success. How is that possible ? I haven't added any code because I have no idea where the bug is.

Server: Detects FD_ACCEPT. Call to accept () fails.

Client: Call to connect () succeeds. It then detects FD_CONNECT. The following send () succeeds. The send () after that fails (10053 - WSAECONNABORTED).

```
void Server::get_addressinfo() {
    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    const char * p = port.c_str();
    int iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, p, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        throw MyException("getaddrinfo failed.");
    }
}

void Server::create_socket() {
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        throw MyException("socket creation failed.");
    }
}

void Server::bind_socket() {
    int iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int) result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        throw MyException("bind failed.");
    }
}

void Server::listen_for_connection() {
    int iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        throw MyException("listen failed.");
    }
}

void Server::goLive() {
    get_addressinfo();
    create_socket();
    bind_socket();
    listen_for_connection();
    wait_for(FD_ACCEPT);
    accept_connection();
}

void Server::wait_for(u_int event_type) {
    WSAEVENT event = WSACreateEvent();
    WSAEventSelect(ListenSocket, event, event_type);
    WSAEVENT lphEvents[1] = {event};
    WSANETWORKEVENTS NetworkEvents = {0};
    int nReturnCode = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &lphEvents[0], false, WSA_INFINITE, false);
    if (nReturnCode==WSA_WAIT_FAILED) 
        throw MyException("WSA__WAIT_FAILED.\n");
    if (WSAEnumNetworkEvents(ListenSocket, lphEvents[0], &NetworkEvents) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        throw MyException("WSAEnumNetworkEvents => SOCKET_ERROR.\n");
    WSACloseEvent(event);  ***// THIS WAS THE BUG !!!***
}

void Server::accept_connection() {
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        throw MyException("accept failed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message could hardly be clearer, and 'where the bug is' is obviously in the call to `accept()`. But if you don't want answers, don't post the code. It's up to you.

Comment: Why do you close the listening socket if the accept fails? Is this only supposed to ever accept one connection or is this part of a scheme to handle multiple connections?

Comment: I'm starting with only one connection for now. If I can handle that, maybe more will follow at some point in the future :-)

Comment: 1. With the code as it currently s it is impossible for you to know what the error code was. 2. I don't know why you're calling the `wait_for()` method at all. The listening socket appears to still be in blocking mode, so `accept()` will block until an incoming connection arrives.

Comment: i read somewhere that the socket goes into non-blocking mode when you enable events

Comment: Now I know what you mean. I edited out all the debug messages because the code was so confusing. The error code is 10038, just as I wrote in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on the code a little bit and made it better, but the bug was still in there. Now I've found the problematic line:

```
WSACloseEvent(event);
```

After commenting it out, the server accepted the connection.

From the MSDN WSACloseEvent function documentation:

> The WSACloseEvent function closes the handle to an event object **and frees resources associated with the event object**.

I guess this means it freed the socket => hence 10038 - WSAENOTSOCK. I fell for the socket value which was unequal to INVALID_SOCKET. Therefore I thought the socket would be valid. It wasn't...

Comment: You should remove the whole event thing. You don't need it. The `accept()' method already blocks. If you need to time it out, use SO_RCVTIMEO.

Comment: I can reproduce the error. Which is odd, because `WSACreateEvent()` simply calls `CreateEvent()`, `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` simply calls `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx()`, and `WSACloseEvent()` simply calls `CloseHandle()`. So you are actually closing a standard Win32 event, which has nothing to do with sockets. On the other hand, I guess `WSAEventSelect()` is somehow linking them together internally so closing one closes the other.

Comment: @EJP: or, you can use `select()` before calling `accept()`.

Comment: The whole event thing came about when I read the 'graceful shutdown' page on MSDN. It seemed like events were the only way to do that.